# Get sessionCookieName from ServletContext in context.xml of tomcat

Tags: java, session, tomcat, servlet-3.0

How could I get the name of session of current request?

The default name of tomcat session is "jsessionid". Given that I have modified the sessionCookieName configuration in context.xml of tomcat as below to gives multiple tomcat instance run on a same server

```
<Context sessionCookieName="appSessionId">

<!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
<!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
<!--
<Manager pathname="" />
-->

<!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
     on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
<!--
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
-->
</Context>
```

My web app need to know what the name of session of current request is. I have tried such as:

```
request.getServletContext().getSessionCookieConfig().getName()
request.getSession().getServletContext().getSessionCookieConfig().getName()
```

But both of them are null.

My pom.xml as below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.23</version>
</dependency>
```

The tomcat I have used is also 8.0.23, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might want to take a look at what `org.apache.catalina.util.SessionConfig.getSessionCookieName` gives you.

Comment: Hi pvg, many thanks for the information you provided. But I am currently using javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet, didn't know how to get the context from HttpServletRequest.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty confusing, because from what I can tell the following always return null, so I'm not sure what the point in them is!

```
request.getServletContext().getSessionCookieConfig().getName()
request.getSession().getServletContext().getSessionCookieConfig().getName()
```

You need to do:

```
SessionConfig.getSessionCookieName(request.getContext())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Mark. But I am currently using javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet, didn't know how to get the context from HttpServletRequest and pass it into getSessionCookieName().